# Take Picture on camera but no find thumbnail

Tags: android, android-activity

I get the picture from the camera but no official stamp with the following code in the pictures I take.

**Code :-**

```
Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
photo = this.createTemporaryFile("photo", ".jpg");
photo.delete();
cekilenResimUri = Uri.fromFile(photo);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, cekilenResimUri);
startActivityForResult(intent, KAMERADAN_RESIM_AL);
```

**onActivity Result:-**

```
this.getContentResolver().notifyChange(cekilenResimUri, null);
ContentResolver cr = this.getContentResolver();
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
cekilenResim = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(cekilenResimUri.getPath(), options);
editorResim.setImageBitmap(cekilenResim);
```

How can I overcome this problem?

Comment: Why are you deleting the file?

Comment: Because temporary files folder of the same name lest stay.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to get captured image as bitmap. but can’t find thumbnail than you have to add image in gallery.
you can add it by these lines:

```
private void galleryAddPic() {
Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
File f = new File(mCurrentPhotoPath);
Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
this.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
}
```